# The efficiency of a traverse and replace in DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery

A client wants a word split and picked out in two colours within a webpage. Easy enough, here's the function

```
jQuery('body').each(function() {

    var text = jQuery(this).html();
    $(this).html(text.replace(/highlightedtext/g, '<span class="highlight">highlighted<span>text</span></span>'));

});
```

My question is how do I assess the speed of this (it seems like a sledgehammer for a nut)? I started by addressing only the `.content` div but they started sneaking the phrase in other CMS managed content, so I am considering traversing the whole document with `jQuery('body')` but I'm a bit worried about the performance hit.

Is using `jQuery('body')` significantly less efficient than `jQuery('.content, .other-div, .etc')` ?

Comment: There's a couple of related questions but none that address my specific one but feel free to dive in if it is, in fact duplicate

Answer (score 1):

In your code jQuery is only used to find  tag, the heavy lifting is done by a regular expression. 
You could remove the jQuery and replace it with:

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/highlightedtext/g, '...')
```

IMO, the bottleneck in this code is the DOM reflow, i.e. recalculation of positions all elements in the DOM. [See here for details](https://sites.google.com/site/getsnippet/javascript/dom/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom-responsibly)

Furthermore, using jQuery("p, span, div, whatever") to more precisely identify elements with text would just add more overhead of DOM traversing with little benefit to minimizing the reflow.

You can assess the impact of reflow and cost of scripts using the Performance tab on Chrome developer tools (or the equivalent in your browser)